# Can't find world and player folders in terraria folder

Tags: terraria

My OS is Linux Mint 18.1. Yes, I did go to /.local/share/games/terraria/, and yes, hidden folders were shown. But when I went to my terraria folder, I didn't see my player and world files. All I saw was 2 folders named "Content" and "lib64," the terraria.exe and terrariaserver.exe files, and a bunch .dll files, whatever those are. Please help me find my player and world files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be in `.local/share/Terraria` if you are not using a cloudsave

If you are it will be in 
`.local/share/Steam/userdata/<steamID>/105600/remote/`

If it is not there run `find $HOME -iname '*Terraria*'` and it will show you all the locations that are named or contain Terraria